# How to catch PlayerError in nativescript-exoplayer and show a propper alert

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

When the user has connection problems I get this in the console:

```
PlayerError com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to ...
```

I was wondering if it was possible to catch this error and tell the user that they have connection problems and the video can't load.
I'm using this great plugin in nativescript-vue

Here is how I'm using the component in my nativescript-vue app:

```
  <exoplayer
    :src="video.src"
    autoplay="true"
    controls="false"
    height="300"
    @finished="done"
  />
```

Comment: The plugin doesn't implement that, you may take a fork and fire an event from [error callback](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-exoplayer/blob/master/src/videoplayer.android.ts#L248).

Comment: @Manoj you are really the best hope of the community:)) thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the videoplayer.android.js file of the plugin in node_modules:

```
onPlayerError: function (error) {

},
```

So I assigned a callback function to the global object in my component and called the function on the global object in the onPlayerError function.
Works for android now.